# Getting the subscription list under a topic in SNS via AWS SDK for Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have working on a project where I have to get the list of all the endpoint subscriptions that happened under the Application in AWS SNS Application.

```
ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest request = new ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest();
request.setPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn);

ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationResult result = sns.listEndpointsByPlatformApplication(request);
List<Endpoint> endpoints = result.getEndpoints();
for(Endpoint endpoint : result.getEndpoints()){
    //System.out.println(endpoint.getEndpointArn());
    count++;
}
```

The count always is 100 and the list that comes is also same I checked it via printing and getting the data out of it.

Where am I doing wrong. I know there is something connected with the token that we get using **getNextToken()** function but unable to do it.

Please help how to get the total number of endpoint subscription under an Application in SNS via AWS SDK using Java.

Thanks
Ankur :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the returned token to return the next page of results as detailed

So your next request would be:

```
String token = tokenFromPreviousRequest();
ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest request = 
    new ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest();
request.setPlatformApplicationArn(applicationArn);
request.setNextToken(token);

ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationResult result = 
    sns.listEndpointsByPlatformApplication(request);
```

Comment: I don't know about using `null` for the first call - best bet would be to run it and see

Comment: Thanks, I got it running and yes your point of null is correct it didnt went well
:)